# Running a count if a function returns less than a certain number in R

Tags: r, geolocation

I made a function using the Imap package and the gdist function. My function just passes through the lat and long coordinates as variables to measure distance.

I have one particular long/lat that I want to measure the distance from a list of longs/lats. I want to feed this list into my function to measure the distance in miles.

If the distance is less than 50 miles, I want it to count the entry. Ideally, I would get a count of entries within 50 miles of my target lat/long so that I can divide it by the total number of entries so I can get a percent of entries within a 50 miles radius. I hope this makes sense.

I have tried using an if statement but I'm striking out. I tried researching countif statements but I can't find a working one. I am hoping I can integrate a for loop and/or the if statement to count the locations less than 50 miles.

```
SFlong <- -90.0490    
SFlat <- 35.1495

ship <- function(x, y) {
dist <- gdist(
lon.1 = SFlong,
lat.1 = SFlat,
lon.2 = x,
lat.2 = y,
units = "miles",
a = 6378137.0,
b = 6356752.3142,
verbose = FALSE
)
return(dist)
}
```

Here's sample input:

```
structure(list(zip = c("00210", "00210", "00210", "00210", "00210"
), city.x = c("Portsmouth", "Portsmouth", "Portsmouth", "Portsmouth", 
"Portsmouth"), state = c("NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH"), latitude = 
c(43.005895, 
43.005895, 43.005895, 43.005895, 43.005895), longitude = c(-71.013202, 
-71.013202, -71.013202, -71.013202, -71.013202), city.y = c("GARDABAER", 
"GARDAB<c6>R", "???", "HELSINKI", "????????"), count = c(7L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the function to calculate the distance. It works when provided an x and y. I want it to run through a list of lats/longs and find which are less than 50 miles in distance and count them.

I just can't map out the logic of the code that will get me what I want. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated or just a nudge in a general direction. Thank you.

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample input. Don't need much, just a few rows. `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:5, ]))` is nice to generate a copy/pasteable output (if the first 5 rows aren't a suitable example, feel free to pick different rows). It's hard to see how to help without seeing how you are using it. (Also, you take in a `data` argument but don't use it... what's with that?)

Comment: But basically, you want something like `my_distances <- ship(...)`, and then `cnt_less_than_50 = sum(my_distances < 50)`

Comment: Thank you Gregor. I put some sample input. I also took out the data argument, I can't remember why I added that in. Your second comment is helpful but it just returns NA. I want it to run through my entire data set and calculate the distance between SFlon/SFlat and a different lat/long on each row.

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. So that gives me half the input--I see the lat and long in each row of the data you shared. I assume these are the `SFlong and `SFlat` arhuments. But I still need to know what other point(s) to calculate the distances to...

Comment: So SFlat and SFlon are fixed longitude and latitude points. I want to calculate the distance between this location and all the other lats and longs in my data set. I thought by creating a function and setting it to have a fixed lon.1 and lat.1 I could run the others through the function. X and Y arguments are those points that are in the sample input I put up there. So the function would keep the fixed SFlat and SFlong but then take in the lats and longs from the dataset.

Comment: Essentially I will put in ship(35.1495, -90.0490) {random coordinates from my data set} and it will return 1229. Which is the distance in miles from Tennessee to Utah. I want my function to run  through my data set and calculate each distance.

Comment: Oh, you just need a better distance function. `geosphere::distHaversine` is vectorized, so you can do `distHaversine(cbind(SFlong, SFlat), cbind(data$longitude, data$latitude))`. Answer will be in meters, but simple to convert.

Comment: Thank you Gregor!